# R Shiny online app: How to properly stop instance when tab browser is closed?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app deployed online. Each time it runs, it does ~ 10 min of calculations.

If the user closes the tab during the calculations (e.g. because they realised they loaded the wrong data and want to start again), reopening the app does not work. The browser just keeps loading ("Please Wait" is not displayed).

I tried adding
session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
to my server code but it did not help.

Manually stopping the instance in shinyapp.io dashboard does resolve the issue, so I guess that is what I want to cause when the user closes the browser tab.

What is the proper way to solve this? I want the instance to fully stop and the app be ready to start again when the user closes the browser tab.